# Compare Certain Strings (part of sentence) from Paragraph

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a Map,

```
HashMap<String,String> dataCheck= new HashMap<String,String>();
dataCheck.put("Flag1","Additional Income");
dataCheck.put("Flag2","Be your own boss");
dataCheck.put("Flag3","Compete for your business");
```

and a paragraph.

```
String paragraph = "When you have an additional Income, you can be your
 own boss. So advertise with us and compete for your business. We help 
 you get additional income";
```

So what I want to achieve is for every member of the Hashmap, I want to compare it with the paragraph and find a number of repetitions. The match  My output must be as follows:

Flag1 - 2 ,  Flag2 - 1 , Flag3 - 1

So, basically, I just want to get an idea on how I compare certain string with another set of strings.

Update: The Match would be case insensitive.

Comment: I would use `String::indexOf`

Comment: To add to what @GBlodgett suggested, loop through your `HashMap` and use `String::indexOf` to count the number of times the index is `>= 0`.

Comment: Also, `HashMap` does not have an `add()` method. You should be using `dataCheck.put()`.

Comment: @Zephyr, as far as I know, indexOf returns the index of first matched string. But in my case, as shown in the example, additional income is repeated twice.

Comment: @DipendraPokharel - you also need to consider whether you want case to matter.

Comment: @DipendraPokharel There is an overloaded version of `indexOf` that will be of use for you

Comment: Using `String.indexOf` yields terrible performance, especially if the paragraph string is long, because you need to search every value of the map in the whole string. This has quadratic time complexity, which is only acceptable for small datasets. You should consider using something more advanced, i.e. take a look at [Aho-Corasick](https://github.com/robert-bor/aho-corasick), which seems an ideal algorithm for your use case. It even supports case-insensitive searches.

Comment: What about overlapping words? i.e. if you had `"Flag4": "your business"` (which overlaps with `Flag3`. Do you need to consider this hypothetical `Flag4`, or would you just discard it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop with `String.indexOf()` to count occurrences.

In the following code, you'll see we are looping through our `HashMap` and comparing each entry to our `paragraph`.

```
    HashMap<String, String> dataCheck = new HashMap<String, String>();
    dataCheck.put("Flag1", "Additional Income");
    dataCheck.put("Flag2", "Be your own boss");
    dataCheck.put("Flag3", "Compete for your business");

    String paragraph = "When you have an additional Income, you can be your own boss. So advertise with us and compete for your business. We help you get additional income";

    // Now, iterate through each entry in the Map
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : dataCheck.entrySet()) {

        // Keep track of the number of occurrences
        int count = 0;

        // After finding a match, we need to increase our index in the loop so it moves on to the next match
        int startingIndex = 0;

        // This will convert the strings to upper case (so our matches are case insensitive
        // It will continue looping until we get an an indexOf == -1 (which means no match was found)
        while ((startingIndex = paragraph.toUpperCase().indexOf(entry.getValue().toUpperCase(), startingIndex)) != -1) {

            // Add to our count
            count++;

            // Move our index position forward for the next loop
            startingIndex++;
        }

        // Finally, print out the total count per Flag
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + count);
    }
```

---

Here is the result:

```
Flag1: 2
Flag2: 1
Flag3: 1
```

Comment: Using `String.indexOf` yields terrible performance, especially if the paragraph string is long, because you need to search every value of the map in the whole string. This has quadratic time complexity, which is only acceptable for small datasets. You should consider using something more advanced, i.e. take a look at [Aho-Corasick](https://github.com/robert-bor/aho-corasick), which seems an ideal algorithm for your use case. It supports case-insensitive, non-overlapping and whole words searches.